# ¿Cómo obtener un valor desde la base de datos con onclick y luego enviar vía post haciendo submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo un formulario en php el cual obtiene un valor desde la base de datos al hacer clic en el botón confirmar el botón tiene un valor el cual lo envía a la función showcustomer para que por medio de ese valor obtenga un dato a través del evento onclick esta función showcustomer regresa un valor en un div txtHint y a la vez hace submit y debería enviar el valor al formulario salida.php el cual debería recibir el valor que tiene txtHint que contiene dentro la variable del campo de texto del retorno td4 el problema que tengo es que el formulario de salida aparece en null, me he dado cuenta que si cambio el tipo de boton a button obtiene el valor pero no se como enviar haciendo onclick y submit a la vez

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<style>

table,th,td {

  border : 1px solid black;

  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;

}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Obtener Datos</h1>

<form action="salida.php" method="post" id="myform" name="myform"> 


<button   onclick="showCustomer(this.value)" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  

value="1" class="btn btn-lg" style="background-color:#6820c6 !important; color:#ffffff 

!important;">Confirmar</button>

<div   class="input-group input-group-lg m-b-10 col-lg-4">


<p type="text" id="txtHint"> </p>

</div>

</form>

<script>

function showCustomer(str) {
 
  var xhttp; 
   
  if (str == "") {

    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }

  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "getcta2.php?codigo="+str, true);
  xhttp.send().submit();

}

</script>

</body>

</html>


este el el archivo get2.php el cual retorna un valor en un campo de texto y lo regresa a la función
```

```html
<?php

error_reporting(0);

    if(!isset($_SESSION)){ 

        session_start(); 

    }
    
    ob_start();

    
    require '../class/function/curl_api.php';


    require '../class/function/function.php';

    $codigo  = trim($_GET['codigo']);

  
  
    $dataJSON = json_encode(
        array(
            'codigo'            => $codigo
          
        ));
        
if (isset($_GET['codigo'])) {
    $codigo = $_GET['codigo'];

 
    $solicitudJSON2 = get_curl('operacion/obtenercuentas/' . $codigo);


}

if ($solicitudJSON2 != null || $solicitudJSON2 != "") {


  foreach ($solicitudJSON2['data'] as $key => $value) {


    if (isset($value['codigo'])) {
?>

<?php
    }
  }
}


if($solicitudJSON2 = json_encode($solicitudJSON2)) {
 
}

echo "<input type='text' id='td4' name='td4' value='" . $value['CUENTA'] . "'>" . $value['CUENTA'] . "</input>";

if($solicitudJSON2 = json_encode($solicitudJSON2)) {
  error_reporting(0);
}
  
?>
```

este es el formulario de salida el cual debería recibir el valor que había retornado el archivo get2.php por medio de la función

```html
<?php
  $myboxes = $_POST['td4'];

 var_dump($myboxes)
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `.submit()` es de formulario, pero lo estás usando en la petición AJAX `xhttp.send().submit();`, seguramente obtienes un error en la consola del navegador.

Para corregirlo, solo deja `xhttp.send();` y, cuando la petición sea exitosa, aplicas el método al formulario para enviarlo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<style>

table,th,td {

  border : 1px solid black;

  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;

}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Obtener Datos</h1>

<form action="salida.php" method="post" id="myform" name="myform"> 


<button onclick="showCustomer(this.value)" type="button" name="submit" value="1" class="btn btn-lg" style="background-color:#6820c6 !important; color:#ffffff 

!important;">Confirmar</button>

<div   class="input-group input-group-lg m-b-10 col-lg-4">


<p type="text" id="txtHint"> </p>

</div>

</form>

<script>

function showCustomer(str) {
  var xhttp; 
  if(str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }

  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      // Enviar formulario
      document.getElementById('myform').submit();
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "getcta2.php?codigo="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Nota:** Elimina `id="submit"` del botón para evitar que interfiera o sobrescriba el método `.submit()` del formulario. No encuentro la documentación, pero Javascript crea automáticamente variables para elementos que tienen ID definido y por eso no se recomienda usar palabras reservadas o nombres de funciones/métodos para este atributo.

Ejemplo:

```js
// Se puede acceder sin usar document.getElementById() o similares
console.log(campo.value);
// El botón sobrescribe el método submit
console.log(formulario1.submit);
// El segundo formulario conserva el método submit
console.log(formulario2.submit);
```

```html
<form id="formulario1">
    <input id="campo" value="Lorem ipsum">
    <button id="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

<form id="formulario2">
    <input id="otro_campo" value="Lorem ipsum 2">
    <button id="btn_submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ya lo intente de esa forma el error que me da en la consola es   prueba3.php:54 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function

Comment: la id del formulario que asigne es myform el mismo que estoy enviando al ajax pero sigue dando el mismo error